# Get the elements that are overflowing

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, html-table, overflow

Is there anyway to find the elements that are overflowing outside of the div?

So you can edit them somehow, using JQuery for example?

I am trying to make it with an HTML table at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Check the javascript code to verify element is overflowing. This operation on large elements may be expensive.

```js
const p = document.querySelector('.parent');

console.log('Overflow ' + (p.offsetHeight < p.scrollHeight));
```

```css
.parent{
  height: 50px;
  border: 1px solid;
}
.child {
  height: 20
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">1</div>
  <div class="child">2</div>
  <div class="child">3</div>
  <div class="child">4</div>
  <div class="child">5</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer!

What I want to target, are the child elements that are overflowing at the moment!
Not just the element that it is overflowing